# how the weld container service for application in java se environment?

Tags: java, maven, cdi, weld, weld-se

> I am a novice in weld, and through several days exploration but I only know some fundamental concept of weld.

---

> I'm intended to use **weld container** in **java se** environment. And follw [What is the easiest way to have CDI and JPA in Java SE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935977/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-have-cdi-and-jpa-in-java-se/20936694#20936694) my code segment is below:

```
public class SayHello {
    public SayHello(){}
       public void sayHello(){
       System.out.println("Hello");
   }
}
```

---

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld;
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer;

public class UseInject {
    private SayHello obj;
    public UseInject(){}

    @Inject
    public UseInject(SayHello obj){
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public void show(){
        obj.sayHello();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
         Weld weld = new Weld();
         WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
         UseInject ui = container.instance().select(UseInject.class).get();
         ui.show();
         weld.shutdown();
    }
  }
```

> and my application is based on **maven**. Here is the jar dependency segment in **pom.xml**

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.Alpha17</version>
```

> my intention is **inject SayHello object into UseInject Object** so the final output of this application is "Hello".
>   But things are not so smooth, the jvm report the follow **error**:
>
> ### [image]
>
> and through search from internet,there is a saying that build a empty **beans.xml** is ok, and I follow it *can't make effect*. And as for the **main method** I *imitate* [What is the easiest way to have CDI and JPA in Java SE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935977/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-have-cdi-and-jpa-in-java-se/20936694#20936694) I don't know what thing it do, and  [What is the easiest way to have CDI and JPA in Java SE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935977/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-have-cdi-and-jpa-in-java-se/20936694#20936694) use the **@Produces** annotation, I don't know whether I should use it too. And I had intended use it for the SayHello Class, but I don't know which jar should I import in order to use it,so I give up.

---

Now I want to:
***1. know how the weld service for se application in other words what things the main method does?***

---

***2. How can I run my application successfully using weld?***

---

***3. when we should use the annotation @Produces***

---

> And I made reference to a number of relevant issues e.g.[weld and java se](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562472/weld-and-java-se)[How to bootstrap weld-se in a JUnit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076189/how-to-bootstrap-weld-se-in-a-junit-test)etc. but find they are all to senior for me.
>   ***thanks for your attention advance.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 2. How can I run my application successfully using weld?

The error message is telling you that you have to create a file named `beans.xml` under the directory `META-INF`. So to solve the problem just do the following:

1. Directory named `META-INF` under `src/main/resources` directory
2. Create an empty file named `beans.xml` under `META-INF` so that your project is CDI enabled.

> 3. when we should use the annotation @Produces

You use this annotation if you want to use any Java primitive types such as Integer, String, ... as CDI beans, or any type / class in an external library which **does not contain** the `META-INF/beans.xml` file in the classpath.

**Example:**

```
public class SayHello {

    @Produces
    private double pi = 3.14159;
    // the rest of the code
}
```

and you can inject the value of `PI` in another place in your code as:

```
public class UseInject {

    @Inject
    private double pi;  // 3.14159 will be injected here

    // the rest of the code

    public static void main(...) {
        // ....
        UseInject ui = container.instance().select(UseInject.class).get();
        ui.show();
        System.out.println(ui.pi);
        // ...
    }
```

The value 3.14159 should be displayed on the console.

Comment: Thank you, and your solution make effect.